# Select from view takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-view

I have a query against a table that contains like 2 million rows using linked server.

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName,
'SELECT
 PV.col1
,PV.col2
,PV.col3
,VTR.col1
,CTR.col1
,PSR.col1
FROM 
LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl1 PV
INNER JOIN LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl2 VTR 
ON PV.col_id = VTR.col_id
INNER JOIN LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl3 CTR 
ON PV.col_id = CTR.col_id
INNER JOIN LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl4 PSR 
ON PV.col_id = PSR.col_id
WHERE
PV.col_id = ''80C53C9B-6272-11DA-BB34-000E0C7F3ED2''')
```

That query results into 365 rows and is executed within 0 second.
However when I make that query into a view it runs for about minimum of 20 seconds and sometimes it reaches to 40 seconds tops.

Here's my create view script

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview]
AS
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName,
'SELECT
 PV.col1
,PV.col2
,PV.col3
,VTR.col1
,CTR.col1
,PSR.col1
FROM 
LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl1 PV
INNER JOIN LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl2 VTR 
ON PV.col_id = VTR.col_id
INNER JOIN LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl3 CTR 
ON PV.col_id = CTR.col_id
INNER JOIN LinkedDbName.dbo.tbl4 PSR 
ON PV.col_id = PSR.col_id')
```

then

```
Select * from myview where PV.col_id = '80C53C9B-6272-11DA-BB34-000E0C7F3ED2'
```

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Compare the query plans (CTRL-L). I suspect the second one doesn't apply the filter until after the data is pulled locally.

Comment: If that's the case, what would be the better approach ?

Comment: The execution plan for the first query goes from _Remote Scan_ to _Select_ while the second one goes from _Remote Scan_ to _Filter_ to _Select_ lastly.

Comment: How many different fields do you filter on? You could turn this into a table valued function which automatically builds the required SQL string and submits it to the remote server. Even better would be to create the view on the remote server and link to the view. Are you able to create objects on the linked server?

Comment: Longer term I suggest thinking of solutions to replace your linked server such as table replication as Gordon Linoff suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions !

Answer (score 3):

Your queries are quite different.  In the first, the `where` clause is part of the SQL statement passed to `OPENQUERY()`.  This has two important effects:

- The amount of data returned is much smaller, only being the rows that match the condition.
- The query can be optimized with the `WHERE` clause.

If you need to share the table, I might suggest that you make a copy on the local server -- either using replication or scheduling a job to copy it over.

Comment: I put a where clause in my first query just to show you that I'm querying a specific user, the same when I'm selecting it from the view.

Comment: @seesharp . . . But in the first query, the `where` clause is sent over to the data and optimized with the query on the remote server.  In the second case, *all* the database is brought over and the filtering is handled locally.